# Did Abraham leave Haran before or after Terah died?

Tags: abraham

One of these days I heard from a local rabbi that according to the commandments of bnei noach one must respect father and mother even if it is not literally explicit in the 7 commandments, since Abraham only left Haran after his father died, not to say that he disrespected his father, only he said that Abraham left before his father died, based on what? By tradition? According to him the Torah reversed and did not explain why.

Comment: Please can you clarify this question. The Torah reversed what? You are saying bnei noach need to "copy Avraham, who didn't leave until his father died" then you say "only he said that Abraham left before his father died" and I don't follow at that point.

Comment: That's what a rabbi said about the need to fulfill father and mother, that as Abraham was a Gentile he respected his father leaving Ur after he died, this is in the Torah only that this rabbi said that in fact Abraham left Ur before his father died, he wanted to know if this is inequality or he took it from a tradition

Answer (score 3):

וימת תרח בחרן. לְאַחַר שֶׁיָּצָא אַבְרָם מֵחָרָן וּבָא לְאֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן, וְהָיָה שָׁם יוֹתֵר מִשִּׁשִּׁים שָׁנָה; שֶׁהֲרֵי כָתוּב וְאַבְרָם בֶּן חָמֵשׁ שָׁנִים וְשִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה בְּצֵאתוֹ מֵחָרָן וְתֶרַח בֶּן שִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה כְּשֶׁנּוֹלַד אַבְרָם, הֲרֵי קמ"ה לְתֶרַח; כְּשֶׁיָּצָא אַבְרָם מֵחָרָן עֲדַיִן נִשְׁאֲרוּ מִשְּׁנוֹתָיו הַרְבֵּה, וְלָמָּה הִקְדִּים הַכָּתוּב מִיתָתוֹ שֶׁל תֶּרַח לִיצִיאָתוֹ שֶׁל אַבְרָם? שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא הַדָּבָר מְפֻרְסָם לַכֹּל וְיֹאמְרוּ לֹא קִיֵּם אַבְרָם אֶת כְּבוֹד אָבִיו, שֶׁהִנִּיחוֹ זָקֵן וְהָלַךְ לוֹ, לְפִיכָךְ קְרָאוֹ הַכָּתוּב מֵת, שֶׁהָרְשָׁעִים אַף בְּחַיֵּיהֶם קְרוּיִים מֵתִים, וְהַצַּדִּיקִים אַף בְּמִיתָתָן קְרוּיִים חַיִּים, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וּבְנָיָהוּ בֶן יְהוֹיָדָע בֶּן אִישׁ חי (שְׁמוּאֵל ב' כ"ג):

AND TERAH DIED IN
HARAN after Abram had left Haran (as related in the next chapter) and had come to the land of Canaan and had been there more than sixty years. For it is written, (Genesis 12:4) “And Abram was seventy five years old when he left Haran”, and Terah was seventy years old when Abram was born (Genesis 11:26), making Terah 145 years old when Abram left Haran, so that there were then many years of his life left (i. e. he lived many years after that — as a matter of fact, 60 years, as he was 205 years old when he died). Why, then, does Scripture mention the death of Terah before the departure of Abram? In order that this matter (his leaving home during his father’s lifetime) might not become known to all, lest people should say that Abram did not show a son’s respect to his father, for he left him in his old age and went his way. That is why Scripture speaks of him as dead (Genesis Rabbah 39:7). For indeed the wicked even while alive are called dead and the righteous even when dead are called living, as it is said, (2 Samuel 23:20) “And Benaiah the son of Jehoiada the son of a living man” - Rashi on Genesis 11:32

Comment: But then the Torah is excusing Abraham for having left before his father died for the wicked even alive are as dead? Isn't this about respecting your father and mother unconditional then? Does it depend on whether the individual is a wicked or not?

Comment: @Thales - Abraham left Haran because G-d told him to, but the Torah just doesn’t wish to publicize it

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Terah left Ur Kasdim with his family in the hebrew year 2000.

Terah was born in the Jewish year 1878.

And Terah took Abram his son and Lot the son of Haran, his grandson, and Sarai his daughter in law, the wife of Abram his son, and they went forth with them from Ur of the Chaldees to go to the land of Canaan, *in the Jewish year*,  and they came as far as Haran and settled there.

And the days of Terah were two hundred and five years, and Terah died in Haran.

Comment: He mentioned Ur but he must have confused the events, which does not explain the issue of him saying that Abraham left before his father died when the Torah says that first his father died and then he left, as he said the Torah portrayed it like this not to say that Abraham disrespected his father by leaving before his death.

Comment: @Thales They had a stop over at Haran. It was not a direct flight. Air Iraq didn't operate directly into Tel Aviv!